# Bash script not running (sed,grep,sort)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a script that I want to apply on a csv file called michael-jordan-nba-career-regular-season-stats-by-game.csv .
I'm just trying very basic stuff, with bash (NOT AWK).
But when I run the script, nothing happens. It's strange because only trying to run the first to sed commands, the script already does nothing.

The script

```
#!/bin/bash

    sed s/CHI/Chicago/g  michael-jordan-nba-career-regular-season-stats-by-game.csv |  #Replacing CHI with Chicago. If it could be only for column 8, better.
    sed s/WAS/Washington/g | #Replacing WAS with Washington. If it could be only for column 8, better.
    grep -v 1985         |   #There is only 1 year column, the first one. Trying to filter out 1985
    sort -n -k 32,32     |   #Trying to sort by column 32, which is PTS
    sed s/1/Home/$9      |   #Trying to replace 1 from column 9 with "Home"
    sed s/0/Away/$9         #Trying to replace 0 from column 9 with "Away"
```

The calling:

```
./b.sh <filename>
```

The file input:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,2,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,3,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
1985,10,10,11/15/1984,21,272,21.74469541,CHI,1,BOS,0,-20,1,33,12,24,0.5,0,1,0,3,3,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,4,27,17.1
1985,11,11,11/17/1984,21,274,21.75017112,CHI,1,PHI,0,-9,1,44,4,17,0.235,0,0,,8,8,1,0,5,5,7,5,2,4,5,16,12.5
1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,-17,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,-10,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
1985,14,14,11/23/1984,21,280,21.76659822,CHI,0,SEA,1,19,1,30,9,13,0.692,0,0,,5,6,0.833,0,4,4,3,4,1,4,4,23,19.5
1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,-10,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
1985,16,16,11/27/1984,21,284,21.77754962,CHI,0,GSW,0,-6,1,24,6,10,0.6,0,0,,1,1,1,0,2,2,3,3,2,4,1,13,11.1
1985,17,17,11/29/1984,21,286,21.78302533,CHI,0,PHO,0,-5,1,30,9,17,0.529,1,1,1,3,4,0.75,1,2,3,2,2,0,2,5,22,14
1985,18,18,11/30/1984,21,287,21.78576318,CHI,0,LAC,1,4,1,37,9,15,0.6,0,0,,2,4,0.5,2,3,5,5,3,0,4,4,20,15.5
1985,19,19,12/2/1984,21,289,21.79123888,CHI,0,LAL,1,1,1,42,7,13,0.538,0,0,,6,8,0.75,2,0,2,3,1,1,4,3,20,12.9
1985,20,20,12/4/1984,21,291,21.79671458,CHI,1,NJN,1,15,1,35,7,13,0.538,0,0,,6,6,1,1,2,3,6,1,0,3,3,20,16
1985,21,21,12/7/1984,21,294,21.80492813,CHI,1,NYK,1,2,1,43,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,5,7,0.714,1,1,2,3,2,0,6,5,21,9.3
1985,22,22,12/8/1984,21,295,21.80766598,CHI,1,DAL,1,2,1,35,10,23,0.435,0,0,,0,0,,4,3,7,2,0,2,2,3,20,11.2
1985,23,23,12/11/1984,21,298,21.81587953,CHI,1,DET,0,-7,1,37,13,28,0.464,0,1,0,1,3,0.333,1,7,8,6,2,0,3,4,27,16.2
1985,24,24,12/12/1984,21,299,21.81861739,CHI,0,DET,0,-7,1,30,6,17,0.353,0,2,0,9,10,0.9,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,21,12.5
1985,25,25,12/14/1984,21,301,21.82409309,CHI,0,NJN,0,-2,1,44,12,25,0.48,0,0,,10,10,1,2,6,8,8,1,0,0,4,34,29.5
1985,26,26,12/15/1984,21,302,21.82683094,CHI,1,PHI,0,-12,1,27,7,16,0.438,0,0,,0,0,,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,14,7.2
1985,27,27,12/18/1984,21,305,21.83504449,CHI,1,HOU,0,-8,1,45,8,20,0.4,0,1,0,2,4,0.5,1,2,3,8,3,0,1,2,18,14.5
1985,28,28,12/20/1984,21,307,21.84052019,CHI,0,ATL,1,3,1,41,12,22,0.545,0,0,,10,16,0.625,4,4,8,7,5,1,7,5,34,26.6
1985,29,29,12/22/1984,21,309,21.84599589,CHI,1,BOS,1,25,1,35,12,18,0.667,0,0,,8,8,1,1,11,12,8,0,3,3,3,32,31.7
1985,30,30,12/27/1984,21,314,21.85968515,CHI,1,CLE,1,4,1,44,20,33,0.606,0,1,0,5,5,1,2,5,7,11,3,0,3,1,45,40.1
1985,31,31,12/29/1984,21,316,21.86516085,CHI,1,ATL,0,-3,1,39,7,18,0.389,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,5,0,0,3,6,21,10.1
1985,32,32,1/2/1985,21,320,21.87611225,CHI,0,ATL,0,-14,1,34,10,14,0.714,0,0,,5,6,0.833,1,6,7,4,3,0,4,2,25,22.3
1985,33,33,1/4/1985,21,322,21.88158795,CHI,1,MIL,1,5,1,38,9,16,0.563,0,1,0,4,5,0.8,0,2,2,6,3,0,0,4,22,20.2
1985,34,34,1/5/1985,21,323,21.8843258,CHI,0,NYK,0,-6,1,42,16,25,0.64,0,0,,10,11,0.909,4,3,7,4,2,1,3,3,42,35.5
1985,35,35,1/9/1985,21,327,21.89527721,CHI,0,BOS,0,-3,1,42,12,24,0.5,0,0,,12,13,0.923,4,2,6,6,2,1,4,4,36,28.3
1985,36,36,1/11/1985,21,329,21.90075291,CHI,1,NYK,1,16,1,30,8,14,0.571,0,0,,7,7,1,2,4,6,5,2,0,5,3,23,18.3
1985,37,37,1/12/1985,21,330,21.90349076,CHI,0,CLE,0,-3,1,36,10,21,0.476,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,4,8,12,3,1,0,3,5,24,15.8
1985,38,38,1/14/1985,21,332,21.90896646,CHI,1,DEN,1,9,1,43,11,16,0.688,0,0,,13,15,0.867,2,12,14,15,3,1,6,3,35,39.4
1985,39,39,1/16/1985,21,334,21.91444216,CHI,0,NJN,0,-6,1,44,8,17,0.471,0,1,0,11,12,0.917,1,6,7,7,2,0,6,3,27,20.1
1985,40,40,1/17/1985,21,335,21.91718001,CHI,1,CLE,1,5,1,40,8,20,0.4,0,0,,9,12,0.75,0,4,4,6,2,2,3,4,25,17.2
1985,41,41,1/19/1985,21,337,21.92265572,CHI,0,IND,0,-3,1,41,15,27,0.556,2,4,0.5,6,8,0.75,2,10,12,7,3,2,2,5,38,34
1985,42,42,1/22/1985,21,340,21.93086927,CHI,1,POR,1,8,1,39,11,20,0.55,0,1,0,7,7,1,1,11,12,5,2,0,4,4,29,23.3
1985,43,43,1/25/1985,21,343,21.93908282,CHI,1,SEA,1,17,1,37,6,15,0.4,0,1,0,10,10,1,2,2,4,8,4,2,1,3,22,24.7
1985,44,44,1/26/1985,21,344,21.94182067,CHI,1,ATL,1,13,1,43,17,24,0.708,0,0,,11,11,1,1,7,8,10,0,4,5,3,45,41.4
1985,45,45,1/29/1985,21,347,21.95003422,CHI,1,KCK,1,6,1,38,11,17,0.647,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,7,7,7,3,0,1,3,26,25.5
1985,46,46,1/30/1985,21,348,21.95277207,CHI,0,WSB,0,-11,1,41,12,19,0.632,0,0,,14,15,0.933,0,7,7,8,4,0,4,3,38,35.6
1985,47,47,2/1/1985,21,350,21.95824778,CHI,0,PHI,0,-11,1,37,9,16,0.563,0,2,0,13,14,0.929,0,6,6,5,2,0,3,5,31,25.3
1985,48,48,2/5/1985,21,354,21.96919918,CHI,1,BOS,0,-4,1,45,14,25,0.56,0,1,0,13,14,0.929,4,8,12,7,4,1,1,6,41,40.1
1985,49,49,2/7/1985,21,356,21.97467488,CHI,0,CLE,0,-9,1,38,8,17,0.471,0,0,,7,8,0.875,3,1,4,7,4,0,7,6,23,15.8
1985,50,50,2/12/1985,21,361,21.98836413,CHI,1,DET,1,13,1,45,19,31,0.613,0,0,,11,13,0.846,7,8,15,5,4,0,6,5,49,40.9
1985,51,51,2/15/1985,21,364,21.99657769,CHI,1,IND,0,-18,1,37,8,20,0.4,0,1,0,1,2,0.5,1,6,7,6,0,2,4,1,17,9.5
1985,52,52,2/17/1985,22,0,22,CHI,0,MIL,0,-20,1,34,9,15,0.6,0,0,,8,8,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,5,1,26,20.2
1985,53,53,2/19/1985,22,2,22.0054757,CHI,1,LAL,0,-10,1,30,6,13,0.462,0,2,0,4,5,0.8,4,2,6,8,0,0,3,5,16,12.9
1985,54,54,2/22/1985,22,5,22.01368925,CHI,0,BOS,0,-10,1,42,8,18,0.444,0,0,,10,12,0.833,1,3,4,7,3,0,3,3,26,21.1
1985,55,55,2/23/1985,22,6,22.0164271,CHI,1,GSW,1,15,1,32,15,20,0.75,0,0,,8,8,1,1,4,5,5,3,0,0,4,38,36.8
1985,56,56,2/26/1985,22,9,22.02464066,CHI,1,CLE,0,-5,1,48,12,27,0.444,0,1,0,4,4,1,3,6,9,5,0,0,1,4,28,18.7
1985,57,57,2/27/1985,22,10,22.02737851,CHI,0,DET,0,-9,1,35,8,17,0.471,0,1,0,8,9,0.889,1,5,6,2,4,1,4,3,24,18
1985,58,58,3/1/1985,22,12,22.03285421,CHI,1,NYK,1,5,1,38,6,15,0.4,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,8,10,10,3,0,7,2,21,17.7
1985,59,59,3/3/1985,22,14,22.03832991,CHI,1,NJN,0,-4,1,41,13,21,0.619,0,0,,11,12,0.917,6,8,14,5,3,1,3,2,37,37.1
1985,60,60,3/5/1985,22,16,22.04380561,CHI,1,WSB,1,5,1,44,12,23,0.522,0,0,,13,17,0.765,2,7,9,8,2,1,2,3,37,32.7
1985,61,61,3/6/1985,22,17,22.04654346,CHI,0,BOS,1,3,1,42,13,28,0.464,0,0,,7,7,1,2,5,7,3,5,2,5,2,33,24.2
1985,62,62,3/8/1985,22,19,22.05201916,CHI,1,LAC,1,16,1,28,7,13,0.538,1,2,0.5,11,14,0.786,2,6,8,7,0,1,1,3,26,25.1
1985,63,63,3/9/1985,22,20,22.05475702,CHI,1,UTA,0,-6,1,38,9,21,0.429,1,1,1,9,16,0.563,2,4,6,4,5,0,6,5,28,16.5
1985,64,64,3/11/1985,22,22,22.06023272,CHI,0,WSB,0,-7,1,34,6,14,0.429,0,0,,9,10,0.9,1,3,4,4,0,0,4,2,21,12.8
1985,65,65,3/12/1985,22,23,22.06297057,CHI,1,DET,1,1,1,39,11,24,0.458,0,1,0,10,11,0.909,3,5,8,4,1,0,5,2,32,20.8
1985,66,66,3/14/1985,22,25,22.06844627,CHI,0,NYK,0,-9,1,34,5,18,0.278,0,0,,6,11,0.545,1,2,3,8,1,0,1,3,16,9.1
1985,67,67,3/15/1985,22,26,22.07118412,CHI,1,PHO,1,6,1,42,11,15,0.733,0,0,,5,6,0.833,1,8,9,14,2,2,6,3,27,29.6
1985,68,68,3/17/1985,22,28,22.07665982,CHI,1,MIL,1,2,1,48,11,25,0.44,0,3,0,10,13,0.769,6,5,11,16,1,1,3,5,32,31.3
1985,69,69,3/19/1985,22,30,22.08213552,CHI,0,HOU,0,-6,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,9,10,0.9,2,2,4,7,2,1,7,3,31,21
1985,70,70,3/20/1985,22,31,22.08487337,CHI,0,SAS,0,-8,1,43,14,23,0.609,0,1,0,10,12,0.833,3,4,7,4,3,0,2,5,38,31.8
1985,71,71,3/23/1985,22,34,22.09308693,CHI,0,DAL,1,10,1,43,5,17,0.294,0,0,,10,10,1,3,6,9,10,2,1,1,1,20,22.3
1985,72,72,3/24/1985,22,35,22.09582478,CHI,0,UTA,0,-18,1,35,9,24,0.375,0,0,,8,11,0.727,3,6,9,6,4,2,3,2,26,21.3
1985,73,73,3/26/1985,22,37,22.10130048,CHI,1,IND,1,1,1,40,13,24,0.542,0,1,0,12,13,0.923,4,5,9,5,3,0,3,5,38,31.8
1985,74,74,3/28/1985,22,39,22.10677618,CHI,0,CLE,0,-8,1,41,11,25,0.44,1,3,0.333,12,14,0.857,4,4,8,10,2,0,2,4,35,30.5
1985,75,75,3/30/1985,22,41,22.11225188,CHI,1,PHI,0,-5,1,42,13,19,0.684,1,1,1,11,13,0.846,2,3,5,6,1,0,3,1,38,33.2
1985,76,76,4/2/1985,22,44,22.12046543,CHI,1,NJN,1,14,1,44,12,19,0.632,0,0,,7,8,0.875,5,3,8,9,3,0,7,1,31,28.4
1985,77,77,4/3/1985,22,45,22.12320329,CHI,0,WSB,1,9,1,40,12,19,0.632,0,1,0,1,3,0.333,1,5,6,3,4,0,2,5,25,20
1985,78,78,4/5/1985,22,47,22.12867899,CHI,0,PHI,0,-3,1,38,13,21,0.619,0,1,0,14,15,0.933,0,1,1,5,3,0,2,6,40,32.5
1985,79,79,4/6/1985,22,48,22.13141684,CHI,0,ATL,1,3,1,43,12,18,0.667,0,0,,9,9,1,2,5,7,4,3,2,7,4,33,26.7
1985,80,80,4/8/1985,22,50,22.13689254,CHI,0,IND,0,-4,1,39,6,20,0.3,0,1,0,10,14,0.714,2,6,8,5,3,0,5,2,22,12.7
1985,81,81,4/12/1985,22,54,22.14784394,CHI,1,ATL,0,-11,1,36,11,16,0.688,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,1,3,6,5,0,7,3,28,23.5
1985,82,82,4/13/1985,22,55,22.15058179,CHI,0,NJN,0,-12,1,40,9,24,0.375,1,5,0.2,10,11,0.909,2,0,2,9,1,0,4,3,29,18.9
1986,1,1,10/25/1985,22,250,22.6844627,CHI,1,CLE,1,1,1,39,13,26,0.5,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,3,6,3,3,0,3,5,29,18.7
1986,2,2,10/26/1985,22,251,22.68720055,CHI,1,DET,1,3,1,41,9,24,0.375,0,0,,15,16,0.938,2,5,7,6,2,3,6,5,33,22.6
1986,3,3,10/29/1985,22,254,22.6954141,CHI,0,GSW,1,6,1,18,6,10,0.6,0,0,,0,0,,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,12,8
1986,4,4,3/15/1986,23,26,23.07118412,CHI,1,MIL,0,-9,0,13,4,7,0.571,0,0,,4,7,0.571,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,12,8.4
1986,5,5,3/17/1986,23,28,23.07665982,CHI,0,ATL,0,-10,0,14,4,16,0.25,0,1,0,9,10,0.9,3,1,4,1,7,1,1,0,17,16.8
1986,6,6,3/19/1986,23,30,23.08213552,CHI,0,PHI,0,-6,0,15,4,14,0.286,0,2,0,4,6,0.667,4,0,4,3,2,2,1,1,12,9.9
1986,7,7,3/21/1986,23,32,23.08761123,CHI,0,BOS,0,-21,0,16,7,16,0.438,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,20,11.8
1986,8,8,3/22/1986,23,33,23.09034908,CHI,0,CLE,0,-26,0,16,4,13,0.308,0,0,,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,-0.3
1986,9,9,3/25/1986,23,36,23.09856263,CHI,1,NYK,1,13,0,19,5,12,0.417,0,1,0,9,9,1,1,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,19,13.8
1986,10,10,3/28/1986,23,39,23.10677618,CHI,0,NJN,0,-11,0,22,9,15,0.6,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,1,1,3,5,0,3,4,22,17.1
1986,11,11,3/29/1986,23,40,23.10951403,CHI,0,NYK,1,10,0,23,10,17,0.588,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,1,0,1,1,1,3,4,2,24,15
1986,12,12,4/1/1986,23,43,23.11772758,CHI,0,MIL,0,-9,0,26,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,12,12,1,1,4,5,2,1,3,1,2,28,24.6
1986,13,13,4/3/1986,23,45,23.12320329,CHI,0,IND,1,1,0,28,12,19,0.632,0,0,,2,4,0.5,1,4,5,3,3,2,3,1,26,21.7
1986,14,14,4/5/1986,23,47,23.12867899,CHI,1,ATL,1,5,0,31,10,21,0.476,2,3,0.667,8,9,0.889,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,1,30,19.6
1986,15,15,4/7/1986,23,49,23.13415469,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,31,10,18,0.556,1,3,0.333,5,5,1,1,4,5,7,1,3,2,3,26,24.1
1986,16,16,4/8/1986,23,50,23.13689254,CHI,0,ATL,0,-13,1,33,12,25,0.48,0,2,0,6,6,1,1,5,6,6,2,1,7,2,30,18.6
1986,17,17,4/11/1986,23,53,23.14510609,WAS,1,WSB,1,2,1,37,12,36,0.333,0,1,0,7,10,0.7,1,4,5,2,3,1,2,5,31,12.4
1986,18,18,4/13/1986,23,55,23.15058179,WAS,0,CLE,0,-7,1,29,11,23,0.478,0,2,0,7,7,1,0,3,3,4,4,0,2,4,29,21.4
```

Expected output:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1986,1,1,10/25/1985,22,250,22.6844627,Chicago,Home,CLE,1,1,1,39,13,26,0.5,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,3,6,3,3,0,3,5,29,18.7
1986,2,2,10/26/1985,22,251,22.68720055,Chicago,Home,DET,1,3,1,41,9,24,0.375,0,0,,15,16,0.938,2,5,7,6,2,3,6,5,33,22.6
1986,3,3,10/29/1985,22,254,22.6954141,Chicago,Away,GSW,1,6,1,18,6,10,0.6,0,0,,0,0,,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,12,8
1986,4,4,3/15/1986,23,26,23.07118412,Chicago,Home,MIL,0,-9,0,13,4,7,0.571,0,0,,4,7,0.571,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,12,8.4
1986,5,5,3/17/1986,23,28,23.07665982,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-10,0,14,4,16,0.25,0,1,0,9,10,0.9,3,1,4,1,7,1,1,0,17,16.8
1986,6,6,3/19/1986,23,30,23.08213552,Chicago,Away,PHI,0,-6,0,15,4,14,0.286,0,2,0,4,6,0.667,4,0,4,3,2,2,1,1,12,9.9
1986,7,7,3/21/1986,23,32,23.08761123,Chicago,Away,BOS,0,-21,0,16,7,16,0.438,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,20,11.8
1986,8,8,3/22/1986,23,33,23.09034908,Chicago,Away,CLE,0,-26,0,16,4,13,0.308,0,0,,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,-0.3
1986,9,9,3/25/1986,23,36,23.09856263,Chicago,Home,NYK,1,13,0,19,5,12,0.417,0,1,0,9,9,1,1,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,19,13.8
1986,10,10,3/28/1986,23,39,23.10677618,Chicago,Away,NJN,0,-11,0,22,9,15,0.6,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,1,1,3,5,0,3,4,22,17.1
1986,11,11,3/29/1986,23,40,23.10951403,Chicago,Away,NYK,1,10,0,23,10,17,0.588,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,1,0,1,1,1,3,4,2,24,15
1986,12,12,04/01/1986,23,43,23.11772758,Chicago,Away,MIL,0,-9,0,26,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,12,12,1,1,4,5,2,1,3,1,2,28,24.6
1986,13,13,04/03/1986,23,45,23.12320329,Chicago,Away,IND,1,1,0,28,12,19,0.632,0,0,,2,4,0.5,1,4,5,3,3,2,3,1,26,21.7
1986,14,14,04/05/1986,23,47,23.12867899,Chicago,Home,ATL,1,5,0,31,10,21,0.476,2,3,0.667,8,9,0.889,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,1,30,19.6
1986,15,15,04/07/1986,23,49,23.13415469,Chicago,Home,MIL,1,6,1,31,10,18,0.556,1,3,0.333,5,5,1,1,4,5,7,1,3,2,3,26,24.1
1986,16,16,04/08/1986,23,50,23.13689254,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-13,1,33,12,25,0.48,0,2,0,6,6,1,1,5,6,6,2,1,7,2,30,18.6
1986,17,17,04/11/1986,23,53,23.14510609,Washington,Home,WSB,1,2,1,37,12,36,0.333,0,1,0,7,10,0.7,1,4,5,2,3,1,2,5,31,12.4
1986,18,18,4/13/1986,23,55,23.15058179,Washington,Away,CLE,0,-7,1,29,11,23,0.478,0,2,0,7,7,1,0,3,3,4,4,0,2,4,29,21.4
```

Many thanks.

Once I get the script working, ideally it would be nice to save the result into another script called b.awk, I imagine with `> b.awk`, but I don't where to put it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't want to use awk; fields manipulation is easier with it.

Comment: I know and I will. I just need to provide different scripts and I'm doing the bash one. Later I will need to do with awk, which I agree is more friend user. But currently in order to learn the fundamentals I've been asked to do it with bash.

Comment: Ok, then are you sure that you can use sed, grep and sort? Just like awk they're standard tools but not bash

Comment: Good question. I have to write a full bash script and a full awk script. Which command would be considered bash for data modification???

Comment: See my updated answer for a pure-bash solution. I never thought that I would one day write a sorting algorithm in bash, but in fact it's pretty easy for positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But currently in order to learn the fundamentals I've been asked to do it with bash

I would say that doing it in pure bash is far more than the fundamentals, but here's how you can replace the `sed`, `grep` and `sort` in your use-case.
<sub>**remark:** Here I don't use numerical comparisons for the sorting; I take advantage of the fact that the `PTS` values are positive integers, which allows using them as array indexes (bash arrays can be sparse).</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=',' records=() sorted=()
{
    IFS='' read -r header

    while read -r -a values
    do
        [[ ${values[0]} != 1985 ]] || continue

        case ${values[7]} in
            CHI) values[7]=Chicago ;;
            WAS) values[7]=Washington ;;
        esac

        case ${values[8]} in
            0) values[8]=Away ;;
            1) values[8]=Home ;;
        esac

        pts=${values[31]} 
        sorted[pts]+=${sorted[pts]:+$IFS}${#records[@]}
        records+=( "${values[*]}" )

    done
} < file.csv

printf '%s\n' "$header"

for i in ${sorted[*]} # unquoted expansion
do
    printf '%s\n' "${records[i]}"
done
```

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1986,8,8,3/22/1986,23,33,23.09034908,Chicago,Away,CLE,0,-26,0,16,4,13,0.308,0,0,,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,-0.3
1986,3,3,10/29/1985,22,254,22.6954141,Chicago,Away,GSW,1,6,1,18,6,10,0.6,0,0,,0,0,,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,12,8
1986,4,4,3/15/1986,23,26,23.07118412,Chicago,Home,MIL,0,-9,0,13,4,7,0.571,0,0,,4,7,0.571,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,12,8.4
1986,6,6,3/19/1986,23,30,23.08213552,Chicago,Away,PHI,0,-6,0,15,4,14,0.286,0,2,0,4,6,0.667,4,0,4,3,2,2,1,1,12,9.9
1986,5,5,3/17/1986,23,28,23.07665982,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-10,0,14,4,16,0.25,0,1,0,9,10,0.9,3,1,4,1,7,1,1,0,17,16.8
1986,9,9,3/25/1986,23,36,23.09856263,Chicago,Home,NYK,1,13,0,19,5,12,0.417,0,1,0,9,9,1,1,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,19,13.8
1986,7,7,3/21/1986,23,32,23.08761123,Chicago,Away,BOS,0,-21,0,16,7,16,0.438,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,20,11.8
1986,10,10,3/28/1986,23,39,23.10677618,Chicago,Away,NJN,0,-11,0,22,9,15,0.6,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,1,1,3,5,0,3,4,22,17.1
1986,11,11,3/29/1986,23,40,23.10951403,Chicago,Away,NYK,1,10,0,23,10,17,0.588,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,1,0,1,1,1,3,4,2,24,15
1986,13,13,4/3/1986,23,45,23.12320329,Chicago,Away,IND,1,1,0,28,12,19,0.632,0,0,,2,4,0.5,1,4,5,3,3,2,3,1,26,21.7
1986,15,15,4/7/1986,23,49,23.13415469,Chicago,Home,MIL,1,6,1,31,10,18,0.556,1,3,0.333,5,5,1,1,4,5,7,1,3,2,3,26,24.1
1986,12,12,4/1/1986,23,43,23.11772758,Chicago,Away,MIL,0,-9,0,26,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,12,12,1,1,4,5,2,1,3,1,2,28,24.6
1986,1,1,10/25/1985,22,250,22.6844627,Chicago,Home,CLE,1,1,1,39,13,26,0.5,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,3,6,3,3,0,3,5,29,18.7
1986,18,18,4/13/1986,23,55,23.15058179,Washington,Away,CLE,0,-7,1,29,11,23,0.478,0,2,0,7,7,1,0,3,3,4,4,0,2,4,29,21.4
1986,14,14,4/5/1986,23,47,23.12867899,Chicago,Home,ATL,1,5,0,31,10,21,0.476,2,3,0.667,8,9,0.889,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,1,30,19.6
1986,16,16,4/8/1986,23,50,23.13689254,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-13,1,33,12,25,0.48,0,2,0,6,6,1,1,5,6,6,2,1,7,2,30,18.6
1986,17,17,4/11/1986,23,53,23.14510609,Washington,Home,WSB,1,2,1,37,12,36,0.333,0,1,0,7,10,0.7,1,4,5,2,3,1,2,5,31,12.4
1986,2,2,10/26/1985,22,251,22.68720055,Chicago,Home,DET,1,3,1,41,9,24,0.375,0,0,,15,16,0.938,2,5,7,6,2,3,6,5,33,22.6
```

---

###### Update (printing the header and reversing the sorted output):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=',' records=() sorted=()
{
    IFS='' read -r header

    while read -r -a values
    do
        [[ ${values[0]} == 1986 ]] || continue

        case ${values[7]} in
            CHI) values[7]=Chicago ;;
            WAS) values[7]=Washington ;;
        esac

        case ${values[8]} in
            0) values[8]=Away ;;
            1) values[8]=Home ;;
        esac

        pts=${values[31]}

        sorted[pts]+=${sorted[pts]:+$IFS}${#records[@]}
        records+=( "${values[*]}" )
    done
} < file.csv

sorted=( ${sorted[*]} ) # unquoted expansion

printf '%s\n' "$header"

for ((i = ${#sorted[@]}-1; i >= 0; i--))
do
    printf '%s\n' "${records[sorted[i]]}"
done
```

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1986,2,2,10/26/1985,22,251,22.68720055,Chicago,Home,DET,1,3,1,41,9,24,0.375,0,0,,15,16,0.938,2,5,7,6,2,3,6,5,33,22.6
1986,17,17,4/11/1986,23,53,23.14510609,Washington,Home,WSB,1,2,1,37,12,36,0.333,0,1,0,7,10,0.7,1,4,5,2,3,1,2,5,31,12.4
1986,16,16,4/8/1986,23,50,23.13689254,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-13,1,33,12,25,0.48,0,2,0,6,6,1,1,5,6,6,2,1,7,2,30,18.6
1986,14,14,4/5/1986,23,47,23.12867899,Chicago,Home,ATL,1,5,0,31,10,21,0.476,2,3,0.667,8,9,0.889,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,1,30,19.6
1986,18,18,4/13/1986,23,55,23.15058179,Washington,Away,CLE,0,-7,1,29,11,23,0.478,0,2,0,7,7,1,0,3,3,4,4,0,2,4,29,21.4
1986,1,1,10/25/1985,22,250,22.6844627,Chicago,Home,CLE,1,1,1,39,13,26,0.5,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,3,6,3,3,0,3,5,29,18.7
1986,12,12,4/1/1986,23,43,23.11772758,Chicago,Away,MIL,0,-9,0,26,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,12,12,1,1,4,5,2,1,3,1,2,28,24.6
1986,15,15,4/7/1986,23,49,23.13415469,Chicago,Home,MIL,1,6,1,31,10,18,0.556,1,3,0.333,5,5,1,1,4,5,7,1,3,2,3,26,24.1
1986,13,13,4/3/1986,23,45,23.12320329,Chicago,Away,IND,1,1,0,28,12,19,0.632,0,0,,2,4,0.5,1,4,5,3,3,2,3,1,26,21.7
1986,11,11,3/29/1986,23,40,23.10951403,Chicago,Away,NYK,1,10,0,23,10,17,0.588,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,1,0,1,1,1,3,4,2,24,15
1986,10,10,3/28/1986,23,39,23.10677618,Chicago,Away,NJN,0,-11,0,22,9,15,0.6,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,1,1,3,5,0,3,4,22,17.1
1986,7,7,3/21/1986,23,32,23.08761123,Chicago,Away,BOS,0,-21,0,16,7,16,0.438,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,20,11.8
1986,9,9,3/25/1986,23,36,23.09856263,Chicago,Home,NYK,1,13,0,19,5,12,0.417,0,1,0,9,9,1,1,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,19,13.8
1986,5,5,3/17/1986,23,28,23.07665982,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-10,0,14,4,16,0.25,0,1,0,9,10,0.9,3,1,4,1,7,1,1,0,17,16.8
1986,6,6,3/19/1986,23,30,23.08213552,Chicago,Away,PHI,0,-6,0,15,4,14,0.286,0,2,0,4,6,0.667,4,0,4,3,2,2,1,1,12,9.9
1986,4,4,3/15/1986,23,26,23.07118412,Chicago,Home,MIL,0,-9,0,13,4,7,0.571,0,0,,4,7,0.571,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,12,8.4
1986,3,3,10/29/1985,22,254,22.6954141,Chicago,Away,GSW,1,6,1,18,6,10,0.6,0,0,,0,0,,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,12,8
1986,8,8,3/22/1986,23,33,23.09034908,Chicago,Away,CLE,0,-26,0,16,4,13,0.308,0,0,,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,-0.3
```

Comment: Hi @Fravadona, many thanks for the effort. Two questions: Could it be the sorting the other way around? I mean the higher value on top?. The other question is: The header is gone?

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias it's possible yes, take a look at the update

Comment: I should then just change record with my file name, right? The recordS() is a typo? should be record()?

Comment: The filename to replace is `file.csv`, at the end of the `{ ... }` block. `record` and `records`  are two different variables; the first one stores the current line, the other one stores all the lines.

Comment: The sorting is not ok but thanks anyway for the effort! Kudos. If you find the issue please update the answer, but thanks!

Comment: Ok, the sorting does work, but on the first column :( the years go from the newest to the oldest.

Comment: I found the bug, it should work as expected now

Answer (score 1):

You're not telling `sed`/`grep`/`sort` to read their data from anywhere, so they will all default to reading data from stdin. Change your script to run the first command on the input file that you're passing and pipe all the subsequent commands to the output of that:

```
sed s/CHI/Chicago/g "$1" | #Replacing CHI with Chicago. If it could be only for column 8, better.
sed s/WAS/Washington/g   | #Replacing WAS with Washington. If it could be only for column 8, better.
grep -v 1985             | #There is only 1 year column, the first one. Trying to filter out 1985
sort -n -k 32,32         | #Trying to sort by column 32, which is PTS
sed s/1/Home/$9          | #Trying to replace 1 from column 9 with "Home"
sed s/0/Away/$9            #Trying to replace 0 from column 9 with "Away"
```

Comment: Please see updated my script. Like that? Do you consider the sort and the last 2 sed are correct?

Comment: the last 2 `sed`s are wrong, as `$9` will be evaluated by bash as an empty string; you should use `set -euo pipefail` as the first line after `#!/bin/bash` to force bash to prompt you with an error in cases like this.

Comment: sort is also not ok, because you're using the default column separator (blanks). Try this instead: `sort -t ',' -k 32 -n`

Comment: Ok, many thanks for you input. Coming back to the last 2 sed commands. How could I tell sed to limit the replacement to just one column? Thanks!!

Comment: I think `sed` only knows how to replace the first occurrence or all occurrences, but not some specific occurrence in your input. I guess you'll want to try `awk` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/^1985/!{1p;/\(\([^,]*,\)\{8\}\)0\(.*\)/s//\1Away\3/;/\(\([^,]*,\)\{8\}\)1\(.*\)/s//\1Home\3/;{/CHI/s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{7\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1Chicago\4/p;/WAS/s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{7\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1Washington\4/p}}' input_file
```

```
$ cat script.sed
/^1985/!{
    1p
    /\(\([^,]*,\)\{8\}\)0\(.*\)/s//\1Away\3/
    /\(\([^,]*,\)\{8\}\)1\(.*\)/s//\1Home\3/
    {
        /CHI/s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{7\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1Chicago\4/p
        /WAS/s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{7\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1Washington\4/p
    }
}
```

```
$ sed -nf script.sed input_file
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1986,1,1,10/25/1985,22,250,22.6844627,Chicago,Home,CLE,1,1,1,39,13,26,Away.5,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,3,6,3,3,0,3,5,29,18.7
1986,2,2,10/26/1985,22,251,22.68720055,Chicago,Home,DET,1,3,1,41,9,24,Away.375,0,0,,15,16,0.938,2,5,7,6,2,3,6,5,33,22.6
1986,3,3,10/29/1985,22,254,22.6954141,Chicago,Away,GSW,Home,6,1,18,6,10,0.6,0,0,,0,0,,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,12,8
1986,4,4,3/15/1986,23,26,23.07118412,Chicago,Home,MIL,Away,-9,0,13,4,7,0.571,0,0,,4,7,0.571,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,12,8.4
1986,5,5,3/17/1986,23,28,23.07665982,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-10,0,Home4,4,16,0.25,0,1,0,9,10,0.9,3,1,4,1,7,1,1,0,17,16.8
1986,6,6,3/19/1986,23,30,23.08213552,Chicago,Away,PHI,0,-6,0,Home5,4,14,0.286,0,2,0,4,6,0.667,4,0,4,3,2,2,1,1,12,9.9
1986,7,7,3/21/1986,23,32,23.08761123,Chicago,Away,BOS,0,-21,0,Home6,7,16,0.438,0,1,0,6,7,0.857,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,20,11.8
1986,8,8,3/22/1986,23,33,23.09034908,Chicago,Away,CLE,0,-26,0,Home6,4,13,0.308,0,0,,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,-0.3
1986,9,9,3/25/1986,23,36,23.09856263,Chicago,Home,NYK,1,13,Away,19,5,12,0.417,0,1,0,9,9,1,1,2,3,3,1,0,2,3,19,13.8
1986,10,10,3/28/1986,23,39,23.10677618,Chicago,Away,NJN,0,-11,0,22,9,Home5,0.6,0,0,,4,6,0.667,0,1,1,3,5,0,3,4,22,17.1
1986,11,11,3/29/1986,23,40,23.10951403,Chicago,Away,NYK,Home,10,0,23,10,17,0.588,0,1,0,4,6,0.667,1,0,1,1,1,3,4,2,24,15
1986,12,12,4/1/1986,23,43,23.11772758,Chicago,Away,MIL,0,-9,0,26,8,Home6,0.5,0,1,0,12,12,1,1,4,5,2,1,3,1,2,28,24.6
1986,13,13,4/3/1986,23,45,23.12320329,Chicago,Away,IND,Home,1,0,28,12,19,0.632,0,0,,2,4,0.5,1,4,5,3,3,2,3,1,26,21.7
1986,14,14,4/5/1986,23,47,23.12867899,Chicago,Home,ATL,1,5,Away,31,10,21,0.476,2,3,0.667,8,9,0.889,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,1,30,19.6
1986,15,15,4/7/1986,23,49,23.13415469,Chicago,Home,MIL,1,6,1,31,10,18,Away.556,1,3,0.333,5,5,1,,1,3,2,3,26,24.1
1986,16,16,4/8/1986,23,50,23.13689254,Chicago,Away,ATL,0,-13,Home,33,12,25,0.48,0,2,0,6,6,1,1,5,6,6,2,1,7,2,30,18.6
1986,17,17,4/11/1986,23,53,23.14510609,Washington,Home,WSB,1,2,1,37,12,36,Away.333,0,1,0,7,10,0.7,1,4,5,2,3,1,2,5,31,12.4
1986,18,18,4/13/1986,23,55,23.15058179,Washington,Away,CLE,0,-7,Home,29,11,23,0.478,0,2,0,7,7,1,0,3,3,4,4,0,2,4,29,21.4
```